# Using SharePoint 2010 with Visual Studio Code

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-code

I've been digging around for last couple days but cannot find anything really related to SharePoint development on VS code.

I know there are some extensions but most of them do not support SP 2010, we're going to be doing the migration soon to SP19' but until that happens AND when it does, I would much rather do it in Vscode than SharePoint designer.

If any of you have any suggestions that would be great.

**EDIT:** I've tried out opening direct link, manage to sign in and get the folder structure.. However pretty much all of them (Like Lists, Libraries etc..) have pretty much same structure and same information (Allitems.aspx, DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx) And they all mainly contain pretty much same code. 
Which is :  and  Tags, no actual JS/Functions and etc within them.

Comment: Will you use VSCode for client-side development?

Comment: I am not sure, it is now fully "Developed" entierly on the web, by just messing around with custom options (mainly ticking loads of tickboxes) and using Nintex forms addon. This is completely gray forest to me and seems so not-intuitive as I am used to writing raw code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about Nintex. Sorry about that. But you can use VSCode to edit .aspx pages and you can develop client-side applications using only JavaScript. At VSCode, CTRL+O will open file dialogue and if you type your site pages library URL, you can open SharePoint pages for edit.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing, I had a test environment set up for me,  signed in, got the pages, but they're all pretty much the same, and things like masterpage and etc are not accessible. Hence me going over to stackexchange to look for some help

Comment: If you want to edit master pages, you should access the master page gallery. Your access link should be like this http://myspfarm/sites/Dev/_catalogs/masterpage/. But be careful, do not edit the master page directly. Backup first.

Comment: I'll try it out as I am working on the test devenvironment at the moment, not direct project. I'll try it out, all this "Edit in the web" Feels like wordpress / freewebs freemium package sites to me not to mention half the logic I have to set up on workflows and etc.. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

VSCode usually used to write,debug code for Programmer. SharePoint 2010 can also used it to edit master page code. You could download master page from gallery and then edit with VSCode.

And as you are going to migrate to SharePoint 2019, Modern Page and SPFX Solution will coming in this version. SPFX is need to use Node.js and VSCode to create and debug, see the document, will give you a bright see:

[Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the link, I was already aware of it and honestly - that's what I was using to preprare my self for this position.. However was we can see, things were completely unexpected and any actual coding is yet to be seen :D